# Remove padding of "Google Sign in" when iframe is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-oauth, google-signin

I need to embed the button for sign in with google. And my problem is that when Google recognises my account and uses the personalized button with my info, it uses an iframe with bad padding.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
         data-auto_select="false"
         data-client_id="-"
         data-context="signin"
         data-ux_mode="redirect"
         data-login_uri="-"
         data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-shape="rectangular"
         data-theme="filled_blue"
         data-text="continue_with"
         data-size="large"
         data-logo_alignment="center">
</div>
```

this results to this if personalized button used (if not recognized the button looks all good):
[image]

As you can see in dark theme it is very obvious that there is a white padding around the button inside the iframe of google. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: maybe don't use an iframe

Comment: @Allancoding this is automatically done by google identity script when it detects my account

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work around this issue by wrapping the "g_id_signin" with an outer div and hiding the overflow:

```
div class="flex justify-center">
  <div class="w-[219px] h-[41px] rounded-full overflow-hidden">
    <div 
      class="g_id_signin"
      data-type="standard"
      data-shape="pill"
      data-theme="filled_white"
      data-text="continue_with"
      data-size="large"
      data-logo_alignment="center"
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where "w-[219px] h-[41px] rounded-full overflow-hidden" are tailwindcss classes to set the div width and height, round the border *(because i'm using the rounded google button)* and, mostly important, hide the overflow. You can easily achieve the same results with vanilla css.